# Ways to Specify a required field to be filled by in an unbound form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an unbound form with some required fields that must be field. I have already executed the vba code to achieve just that. Now my question is how do i specify thefields so that he end user can vividly see those fields. I already have an idea of using red stars but i am open to more suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can add (*) symbol in the label that denotes its mandatory to fill.